# How does different sensor(magnetometer, accelerometer) work to make compass - Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have to implement a compass in Java (Eclipse) for Android Platform.

I am required to use NOT the phone's sensor, but a sensor that I am given (Sensortag cc2541)

This sensor has:

Magnetometer, Accelerometer, Gyroscope, etc..

So I was wondering in order to make a compass, which sensors do I exactly need? I am a bit lost. So the magnetometer returns Point 3D (x y z). The accelerometer returns Point 3D as well.

I just need a basic explanation on which sensors and how are they going to function for the creation of a compass

Answer (score 0):

For a simple compass, just [Magnetometer](http://science.howstuffworks.com/magnetometer-info.htm) is needed. It gives you the vector of which it thinks to be north.

Accelerometer and Gyroscope can help you with the calculation by determining how the device is positioned.

Point3D is just a vector. You will need to know some [vector math](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors.html) to fully understand and do calculations.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I understand that. but for example out of the X Y Z value that i can get from the magnetometer, which ones will help me to find north? is it an angle? if yes angle between which and which point?

Comment: its a vector. think of it as an arrow in 3d space. you will need 3 values x y z to represent this arrow. the values are a magnitude. check out the two links provided